# NodeJs setting up production and development

Tags: node.js

I was learning NodeJs advance concepts after going through the basic course.

I am following stepehen grinder course where we would be using his folliwng  [repo](https://github.com/StephenGrider/AdvancedNodeStarter)

I was initially walking through the repo where somethings were sort of new to me

My main question evolves around his [`index.js` file in repo](https://github.com/StephenGrider/AdvancedNodeStarter/blob/master/index.js)
This isn't prime question but first he have done something like this

```
require('./routes/authRoutes')(app);
require('./routes/blogRoutes')(app);
```

Is this equivalent to something like this

```
const auth = require('./routes/auth.js') 
const profile = require("./routes/profile.js")
app.use('/auth', auth)
app.use('/profile', profile)
```

Second, **Primary question**, In his index.js file he have done something like this

```
if (['production'].includes(process.env.NODE_ENV)) {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  const path = require('path');
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
```

This does not make sense to me at all, can someone explain me what does the above code do? and an interesting article which can help me comprehend.

Also, Can someone please tell me what does [`path` module](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html)  do? I went through their do documentation and was able to comprehend that path allows us to access files outside our node project. Is that correct understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning you first question:

It's not the same. `app.use(...)` defines a middleware that gets executed on all and every routes. Here, both routes files export a function which takes one argument: the application (ExpressJS server) instance. 
So, `require('./routes/blogRoutes')` gives you a function `app => {...}`, and by adding parenthesis and the `app` variable as a parameter you immediately execute this function with the current server (application) instance. Which in the end will create all the routes defined in the route file.

Concerning your second question:

The `if` is testing if the NODE_ENV variable is equal to production. If it is in production mode, `app.use(express.static('client/build'));` tells ExpressJS to serve static files from the `client/build` folder. 
The rest of the code `app.get('*', ...)` send the index.html file for calls made to any route except the one defined in the two routes files.
The `path.resolve` only role is to easily build the absolute path of the `index.html` file.

Comment: Ohh. For the first point, this means that we don't need to add following in our model routes? `const express = require('express')
const app = express()` ?

Comment: No, that's why ExpressJS is not imported in routes/authRoutes.js in your example. Because you already initialize an ExpressJS instance (`app`) in your index.js file, and you just pass this instance to the route file, which "apply" all its routes to this instance.

Comment: Makes sense, just a small mistake, you wrote `app.use("*", ...)` instead of `app.get("*", ...)` probably.

Comment: True! Corrected :)